# Xcode 7.3.1 - How display source and disassembly while debugging?

Tags: xcode7.3

I want to simultaneously display source code AND assembly code while debugging with Xcode 7.3.1. (in a split debugging display). My searches have found instructions for one or the other, but not both. The only exception was the following: '
From the run menu, select "Debugger Display" > "Source Only", or "Debugger Display" > "Source and Disassembly"'. However, Xcode 7.3.1 does not have any such choices under the Run tab. Thanks